# Java client serv

Tags: java, client-server

What I need to do basically is a Java client/Server program where the client asks the server to perform an addition or multiplication. The client sends to the server an 
object that contains the requested operation (addition or multiplication) and a sequence of numbers the server has to work on (add or multiply). Numbers are sent from the console, written by the user.

The server recieves the object, does the calculation and returns the answer.This is the code I have this far. I don't know how to put the add function to and object, send it to a server, send te numbers, so the server can act on them.

```
         package esercizio3;
         import java.io.*;
         import java.net.*;

         public class Client{

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket communication = new Socket("localhost",8888);
    BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(
                    new  InputStreamReader(communication.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter(communication.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    request.println(stdIn.readLine());
    String line = response.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    response.close();
    request.close();
    stdIn.close();
    communication.close();


}
   }


 package esercizio3;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

 public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8888);
    Socket communication = listener.accept();
    BufferedReader request = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(communication.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter response = new PrintWriter(communication.getOutputStream());
    String line;
    while((line = request.readLine()) != "FINE"){
            a = request.
            response.println("Hai detto: " +line);
    }

    request.close();
    response.close();
    communication.close();
    listener.close();

}

   }
```

Comment: Your code contains errors, and is not properly formatted. It'll be easier to help if you clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Client**

```
package esercizio3;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket communication = new Socket("localhost",8888);
        BufferedReader response = new BufferedReader(
                                  new  InputStreamReader(communication.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter request = new PrintWriter(communication.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String userInput = stdIn.readLine();
        if (userInput.equals("FINE")){//    All calculations are finished
            request.println("FINE");
        }else{
            StringBuffer sbUserInput = new StringBuffer();
            while(!userInput.equals("SEND")){   //  Get input from user until SEND command received and prepare a string which you have to process in server
                sbUserInput.append(userInput).append(" ");//Add the user input along with a space which eases our server task.
                userInput = stdIn.readLine();
            }
            request.println(sbUserInput.toString());    //  Send it to server
        }
        String line = response.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        response.close();
        request.close();
        stdIn.close();
        communication.close();
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
package esercizio3;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8888);
        Socket communication = listener.accept();
        BufferedReader request = new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(communication.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter response = new PrintWriter(communication.getOutputStream());
        String line;
        while((line = request.readLine()) != "FINE"){
            //  Read each string separated by space in the line and check if it is a number or + Or *
            String[] lineContents = line.split(" ");
            int result = 0;
            for(String lineContent : lineContents){
                //  Check if it is + OR *
                //  Take proper action and update "result"
            }
            //  Send the response back to the client
            response.println("Hai detto: " +line);
        }
        request.close();
        response.close();
        communication.close();
        listener.close();
    }
}
```